# gcloud compute images import SLES 15 SP2 BYOL

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Currently trying to do a gcloud image import in order to bring our own license for SLES 15 SP2 gives:

```
[import-image]: 2020-07-30T23:00:04Z Error running workflow: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-image-54bdm": "TranslateFailed: error: Import of sles-15.2 is not supported. The following versions are supported: [opensuse-15.1, sles-15.1, sles-12.4|5]"
```

I haven't been able to locate any info on when this would be supported. Any pointers or info on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, import is not supported for SLES 15 SP2.
Please see [Compute Engine > Doc > Feature support by operating system](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/os-details#import)

[image: 20200731 - gcloud compute images import SLES 15 SP2 BYOL - pic]